# Hacked cookies in Play for Scala

Tags: http, playframework, session-cookies

Play Framework applications store Session data in a cookie, like so:

```
Cookie:PLAY_SESSION=bd5712f8fb6a7a43935e20f98d6b147181dda9d5-field1=value1&field2=value2
```

Now, assume there are two users in two different browsers, and user 1 takes the cookie of user 2, manages to hack their browser, and replaces their cookie with the one of user 2.

When user 1 makes a request with the changed cookie, will they submit the values of user 2 and process the request normally or Play will detect this?

I'm working in Scala, but I assume this is common functionality for Java as well.

Comment: I doubt it, since detecting such a thing in a generic way is almost impossible.

Comment: And how would it detect that? There are things like csrf tokens that could make some submit call fail, but if someone manages to get the cookie it can also get the csrf token...